# How to get value from json knowing a specifc id in a cURL command

Tags: python, bash, shell, curl

My cURL command returns me some json data like the following :

```
{  
    "all":[  
        {
            "id":"1",
            "actions":[  
                "power",
                "reboot"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "actions":[  
                "shutdown"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"3",
            "actions":[  
                "backup"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Knowing only the `id`, how can I return the `actions` values into a variable ? I know how to parse IDs but how can I get the `actions` ?

Here is the cURL command :

```
#!/bin/bash
IDS=$(curl https://DOMAIN/API -H "X-Auth-Token: $TOKEN" | python -c "import sys, json; print [i['id'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['all']]")
```

`$IDS` will output all IDS from the json.

---

**Exemple:**
If I search for `id = 1`, I will retreive `["power", "reboot"]`

---

I can also retreive actions with :

```
#!/bin/bash
ACTIONS=$(curl -s https://DOMAIN/API -H "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN" | python -c "import sys, json, re; print [ i['allowed_actions'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['servers']]")
```

I thought doing something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
ACTIONS=$(curl -s https://DOMAIN/API -H "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN" | python -c "import sys, json, re; print [ if i['id'] == '1': i['allowed_actions'] for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['servers']]")
```

But I have syntax error.

How can I translate this code into a single command line code ?

```
for i in json.load(sys.stdin)['all']:
    if i['id'] == '1':
        print(i['actions'])
```

Comment: If you want to read `json` files in bash, consider using `jq` instead of calling python.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't want  to install a third party

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the norm is to not use exec in python but since you wanted to be in one line, here you go

```
cat temp | python -c "exec(\"import sys,json \nfor i in json.load(sys.stdin)['all']:\n    if i['id'] == '1':\n        print(i['actions'])\")"
```

While saying this I suggest just creating another python file and let this job be done by that file , Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

From `CLI`, you could use `jq`;

```
curl -s "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random" | jq '.value.joke'
```

In your case, it would probably be something like (not tested) :

```
ACTIONS=$(curl -s "https://DOMAIN/API" | jq '.all.actions')
```

More information/examples for `jq`;

https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/working-with-json-in-bash-using-jq-13d76d307c4